# How to trigger release in travis-ci?

Tags: gradle, travis-ci

I have a project in Github which I use Travis-CI as continuous integration. So far I've been executing the release command using gradle by myself on my computer which in turn will upload the artifacts.

How can I do similarly with Travis-CI? How can I trigger Travis-CI to run gradle release instead of gradle build?

Comment: did you found any solution for above?

Comment: No, I didn’t. I ended up using teamcity to do that.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways.
This depends on how exactly you want to differenciate between a release and a non-release build.
You could e. g. set up different builds for different branches, or you could e. g. do something like the following in your `.travis.yml`:

```
script:
  - [ -z "$TRAVIS_TAG" ] || ./gradlew release
  - [ -z "$TRAVIS_TAG" ] && ./gradlew snapshot
```

On https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/ you find all environment variables you could e. g. use.